# Bootstrap modal doesn't appear in Meteor

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, meteor

I'm trying to get Bootsrap's modal to work but when I click on the button all I get is a black screen, no modal dialog box appears as I expect it to. I'm using meteor.

Here's the code I have:

```
<div class="container">
    <h2>Example of creating Modals with Twitter Bootstrap</h2>
    <div class="modal hide fade in" id="example" style="display: none; ">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <a class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</a>
            <h3>This is a Modal Heading</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <h4>Text in a modal</h4>
            <p>You can add some text here.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <a class="btn btn-success" href="#">Call to action</a>
            <a class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" href="#">Close</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <p><a data-toggle="modal" href="#example" class="btn btn-primary btn-large">Launch
        demo modal</a></p>
</div>
```

I've essentially obtained the code from: http://www.w3resource.com/twitter-bootstrap/modals-tutorial.php for testing purposes.

Comment: I created a blank meteor project with bootstrap and the above code is working fine. Do you have any other js plugins?how did you add bootstrap is it with the meteor bootstrap package?

Comment: Hmmm, I created a blank project and it's working too. I have the standard js plugins included in the packages folder. I also have a few other js plugins but they're not really related to bootstrap. I just did meteor bootstrap add.

Comment: Maybe there are some clashes? JQuery is included by default so you don't have to add it, if you added them with meteor you also don't need them in your plugins folder. Which do you have specifically? Could you try removing one at a time to find when it starts working?

Comment: Are you using the entire HTML as it is from the source? Does your console give any error?

Comment: You could try removing either the "hide" class or the "display: none". I don't think you need both of them.

Comment: Is your modal included in a `<template></template>`?  

I have the same problem in that specific case. I get a blank screen whenever the element calling the modal is nested inside `template`tags. Having a fix for that would be super useful.

Comment: Do you have a git url we could clone?

Answer (score 8):

I had a similar issue.  The problem is a fundamental difference in how Meteor and Bootstrap work.  Meteor assumes that markup can be reloaded at any time.  If any live variables change, Meteor just reloads the template.  Bootstrap on the other hand assumes that the template will only be loaded once, and them modified with javascript at runtime.

What is happening is meteor is loading my modal template.  At some point I'm clicking on something, which causes that modal to appear in javascript.  However, a split second later, a live variable changes which causes the template to load again.  Since the template has the modal hidden, it overrides the javascript that was just trying to show the template.

I solved this by putting the inside of the modal in a different template than the outside.  The outer template doesn't respond to any live variables, so it will hopefully never be reloaded.

Before:

```
<template name="modal">      
  <div class="modal hide fade in" id="settings-modal" data-backdrop="false">
    <div class="modal-header">
    ...
</template>
```

After:

```
<template name="modal">      
  <div class="modal hide fade in" id="settings-modal" data-backdrop="false">
    {{> modalInner}}
  </div>
</template>      

<template name="modalInner">
  <div class="modal-header">
    ...
</template>
```

Comment: Also note that in order to handle closing the modal, you need to put the events handler on the outer template, not the inner.

Comment: Thanks! Solved my own related problem handily, and I appreciate your addressing the larger issue in a useful manner.

Answer (score 4):

Here's an example app which shows how to display a bootstrap modal with Meteor:

- https://github.com/alanning/meteor-modal-example

You can see a live version in action here:

- http://modal-example.meteor.com/

Answer (score 2):

I have figured out a decent solution -- my Modal is it's own template and a session variable controls if it gets displayed.  After it is "rendered" I trigger bootstrap's JS to "open" it.

```
...
{{#if getSession 'isRegisterConfirmation'}}
  {{> registerConfirm}}
{{/if}}
</template>

<template name="registerConfirm">
<div class="modal registerConfirmModal">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
    <h3>Confirm Name / Info</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    You are registering as
    ...
```

The tricky part was tying events between Meteor and Bootstrap.

- On Meteor render -> trigger Bootstrap Modal show
- On Bootstrap Modal hide -> clear session variable from Meteor

This actually works out very well, here's a simplified version of what I've got going on...

```
Template.registerConfirm.rendered = function() {
  var thing = Session.get('thingToConfirm');
  $('.registerConfirmModal').on('hidden', function() {
    Session.set('thingToConfirm', '');
    Session.set('isRegisterConfirmation', false);
  });
  $('.registerConfirmModal').on('shown', function() {
    $('.registerConfirmModal button.confirm').focus();
  });
  $('.registerConfirmModal').modal('show');
};
```

Then triggering the modal is as simple as setting the session variable to true....  all the rest of the interchange is based on events.

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing the same issue.  I removed the 'hide' class from the modal and it worked after that.  **I also had to include the modal in the same template with the link that activates it.**

Instead of

```
<div class="modal hide fade in" id="example" style="display: none; ">
```

Try this

```
<div class="modal fade" id="example" style="display: none;">
```