# Meteor combined with Session.set and jQuery in one call

Tags: javascript, jquery, session, meteor

I'm trying to get something very basic to work in Meteor, where when the user clicks a button a Session.set() is called and then a div is shown. The problem is that if I don't call the Session.set() the behaviour is as expected where the div is shown upon clicking the button. But once I include the Session.set() i need to click twice before the message is actually show. To make sure the behaviour can be reproduced make sure the page is a clean load and not a Meteor refresh!
The code for the HTML is:

```
<head>
  <title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
  {{> home}}
</body>

<template name="home">
  <div>
    <input type="button" id="addButton" value="add">
  </div>
  {{> popup}}
</template>

<template name="popup">
  {{#with messageHelper}}
  <div id="messageDiv" style="display: none">
    message is {{message}}
  </div>
{{/with}}
</template>
```

And here is the Javascript that makes it tick.

```
Template.home.events({
  'click #addButton': function(){
    // **** if this line is commented out, it will work
    Session.set("messageHelper", {message: 'HERE'});
    // ****
    $('#messageDiv').show();
  }
});

Template.popup.helpers({
  messageHelper: function(){
    return Session.get("messageHelper");
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the changed session variable rerenders your template in its original state which sets style="display: none".  The problem is discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15176413/bootstrap-modal-doesnt-appear-in-meteor).  The solution there is to reorganise your template so the reactivity is not in the template where display is being toggled.

An easier solution might be just to use handlebars #if helper to display your template whenever there is a message:

```
<template name="popup">
   {{#with messageHelper}}
     {{#if message}}
       <div id="messageDiv">
         message is {{message}}
       </div>
     {{/if}}
   {{/with}}
</template>
```

No need for .show() in the event handler then.

Comment: that makes sense. takes a while to rewire your thinking paths on how to do stuff with a new framework :) Thanks for the quick reply