# Getting a meteor modal to be dynamic

Tags: meteor, dynamic, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

I'm working w/ a modal template (maybe I shouldn't be?).  On screen, I have a list of products.  When a user clicks on a product, I want the modal to open w/ details of that given product.

Right now, what I'm trying to do is update the subscription of the modal.  However, the OnCreate() and OnRender() are not firing when the modal opens. Right now the rendered, OnRender, created, and onCreated of the modal all fire when the parent template (the product list) is first opened. I need it to happen when a product is clicked and the modal is shown.

Am I attacking this wrong?  Or do I just need to position my subscription somewhere else in the modal?

(adding code - very simple)

```
<template name="parent">
    ...
    <div class="row form-row">
        <div class="col-sm-12 text-right">
            <a class="btn btn-outline" type="button" id="remove">Remove</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    {{> productEditModal}}
</template>

<template name="productEditModal">
    <div class="modal inmodal" id="productEditModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content animated bounceInRight">
                <div class="modal-header">
...

Template.parent.events({

...

"click #aEditProduct": function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    Session.set("productId", this._id);

    $('#productEditModal').modal('toggle');
    $('#productEditModal').modal('show');

Template.productEditModal.onRendered(function() {

    var self = this;
    self.autorun(function() {
        self.subscribe("products", Session.get("bid"), function() {
            var bProduct = BoardProducts.findOne(Session.get("productId")); // some reactive operation
            // do fun stuff with thing
        });
    });

});
```

Comment: are you using bootstrap? then see https://atmospherejs.com/peppelg/bootstrap-3-modal

Comment: show us your code, we can help.

Comment: what does that have to do with the subscription? plus, where is it? (show code). Also, `OnRendered` and `OnCreate` have nothing to do with the modal opening (which is a javascript call -- the DOM elements get created earlier).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bootstrap modal doesn't appear in Meteor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15176413/bootstrap-modal-doesnt-appear-in-meteor)

Comment: I checked the link above.  I will try it, but I don't that that's it.  Unless for some reason this fires the OnCreated or OnRendered more?

Comment: I added "meteor add peppelg:bootstrap-3-modal", but I'm not sure what exactly that added to the problem?

Comment: tried the referenced article.  That did not solve it.  Actually - all it does for me is turn the whole screen dark w/ no content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok, here is how I would approach this, assuming you did `meteor add peppelg:bootstrap-3-modal`

1. parent template: loop over products and display preview

   ```
   <template name="parent">
     {{#each products}}
       {{name}}
       {{pic}}
       etc...
       <a class="btn show-details" type="button">show details</a>
     {{/each}}
   </template>
   ```
2. create a details modal

   ```
   <template name="productDetailsModal">
     <div class="modal" id="productDetailsModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
       <div class="modal-dialog">
         <div class="modal-content">
           <div class="modal-header">
             Details for product {{name}}
             ...
   ```
3. parent template helper to return products cursor:

   ```js
   Template.parent.helpers({
     products() {
       return Products.find();
     },
   })
   ```
4. the event to show details modal for every product

   ```js
   Template.parent.events({
     'click .show-details'() {
       Modal.show('productDetailsModal', this);
     },
   })
   ```

I wrote this off the top of my head and did not test it. Let me know if it works for you.